# How to create a tile (pin to start) of current site opened in Internet explorer app in windows phone 8 on button click?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

My objective is to create a tile (pin to start) of current site opened in Internet explorer in windows phone 8.
We have developed a site.There is a page in the site with a button.When the user navigates to the page in IE app and clicks the button ,we have to add a tile for current page using pin to start feature.
Any help will appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there's any way for an app to know what website is currently being viewed in internet explorer. Also, this can already be done from IE, so not sure why you'd need an app to do it.

Comment: to be clear, you want to create the same usability, only applications can create lives tiles.